# I get "Unsupported account" error when I try auto generate certificate in sidekick

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

When I try "iOS Auto generate provisioning profile and certificate" in sidekick, I get the following error:

> Auto Generation Failed
>
> An error has occured while generating the certificate and mobile provision. Reason: Unsupported account. You should use the Certificate Signing Request tool to generate a certificate. Open it from: Tools -> Certificate Signing Request

I am wondering what could be the cause of this error and how can I resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it explained in the error message how to resolve it?

Comment: Is it a free account or paid one?

Comment: It is a paid account enrolled in developer program.